# PHP - Checkbox in table not returning any value

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox, html-table

When I click the delete button, the values of those checkboxes that are checked in the table are not shown. It is suppose to delete records on the database based on the id but i'm stuck in getting the value of the checkboxes. Please help correct my code. I'm using bootstrap for your information.

PHP

```
$sql = "SELECT id, title FROM box";
$query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

if(isset($_POST['btnDelete'])) {
    $checkbox = isset($_POST['chkDelete']) ? $_POST['chkDelete'] : array();


    for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++)
    {
        $message = $checkbox[$i];
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="content">
            <div id="table">
                <table class="col-md-12 table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf">
                    <thead class="cf">
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php 
                            while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                            {
                                $html = '<tr>
                                            <td data-title="">
                                                <input name="chkDelete[]" type="checkbox" value="' . $result['id'] . '">
                                            </td>
                                            <td data-title="#">' . $result['id'] . '</td>
                                            <td data-title="Title">' . $result['title'] . '</td>
                                            <td data-title="Action">
                                                <a href="edit.php?id=' . $result['id'] . '">Edit</a>
                                            </td>
                                         </tr>';

                                echo $html;
                            }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <input type="submit" name="btnDelete" value="Delete" />
            </form>
            <div class="message"><?php echo $message;?></div>
        </div> <!--//END content-->
```

Comment: The checkbox isn't inside a form, or you haven't explicitly said that the checkbox should belong to that form.

Comment: In addition, you overwrite `$message = $checkbox[$i];` for each iteration, so it would only contain the last iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PHP** (Write `Delete Query` inside `for loop` to delete all `checked` checkbox.)

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['btnDelete'])) 
{
  $checkbox = isset($_POST['chkDelete']) ? $_POST['chkDelete'] : array();
  $id = 0;
  for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++)
  {
    $id = $checkbox[$i];
    $deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM box WHERE id='$id'";
    $DeleteQueryExec = mysqli_query($db, $deleteQuery);
  }
}
?>
```

**HTML** (Put entire `table` inside `<form></form>`)

```
<div class="content">
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <div id="table">
            <table class="col-md-12 table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf">
                <thead class="cf">
                  <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php 
                $sql = "SELECT id, title FROM box";
                $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
                while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                {
                $html = '<tr>
                            <td data-title="">
                                <input name="chkDelete[]" type="checkbox" value="' . $result['id'] . '">
                            </td>
                            <td data-title="#">' . $result['id'] . '</td>
                            <td data-title="Title">' . $result['title'] . '</td>
                            <td data-title="Action">
                                <a href="edit.php?id=' . $result['id'] . '">Edit</a>
                            </td>
                         </tr>';
                echo $html;
                }?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="btnDelete" value="Delete" />
        <div class="message"><?php echo $message;?></div>
    </form>
</div> <!--//END content-->
```

Comment: Finally! Thank you for helping me. Works great!

Comment: Glad It Worked. *Happy To Help* @xenazfire